# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, lamp, forgot-password, mysql-error-2002

I installed [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) on [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) and then set root password on [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin). I forgot the password and now I am unable to login. When I try to change password through terminal I get:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>    '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

How can I fix this? I am unable to open LAMP, uninstall it or reinstall it.

Comment: Probably reinstall it is easier:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31984482/763744

Comment: Reset the password by stopping MySQL and starting it in safe mode skipping the --grant tables

Comment: type this in your terminal " sudo apt-get install mysql-server"

Comment: Start or restart mysql service and check. sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start or sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart

Comment: systemctl start mariadb.service

Comment: systemctl enable mariadb.service

Comment: I had the same problem on my raspberry pi, i used **sudo mysql_secure_installation**, worked for me

Comment: If anybody on arch has this issue, do look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357383/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock-2

Comment: In Ubuntu 20 just  remove the lock file and restart will solve the issue

sudo rm /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.bak/mysqld.sock.lock

Answer (score 374):

I once had this problem and solved it by installing `mysql-server`, so make sure that you have installed the `mysql-server`, not the `mysql-client` or something else.

That error means the file `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` doesn't exists, if you didn't install `mysql-server`, then the file would not exist. So in that case, install it with

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But if the `mysql-server` is already installed and is running, then you need to check the config files.

The config files are:

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf
```

In `/etc/my.cnf`, the socket file config may be `/tmp/mysql.sock` and in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` the socket file config may be `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. So, remove or rename `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, let mysql use `/etc/my.cnf`, then the problem may solved.

Comment: You can have the mysql daemon running, and the mysql-server-core installed, but you need to install the mysql-server, which is the binaries AND the system database setup !

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` to install mysql on ubuntu

Comment: If I had to explain technically , I would say 1)If you are running "mysql -u <user_name> -h <MySQL_Server_address> -p", you are actually running mysql client to access the mysql server. If you do not have mysql server installed on the address/IP address you mentioned with '-h', the above error will pop up. This is because it is not able to connect to MySQL server through the socket mysql.sock 2) If Mysql-server is already installed, it should be running.If it's not, you will observe the same error. So get it running on the server you specified.

Comment: This can also occur if you try to change the directory where the database is stored, but imput the wrong directory in the configuration file (like a typo). Instead of telling you the typo directory does not exist, it will tell you that you lack permission to access it.

Comment: Nothing here worked for me. What did: I removed mysql completely: https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d and then installed mariadb: https://getgrav.org/blog/mac-os-x-apache-setup-mysql-vhost-apc. Everything works now :)

Comment: As a first step I would recommend an attempt to restart the server process (see other's distinctions of server v.s client). Try sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart. Usually, re-installation isn't necessary. I would recommend you to first check the log files. Not just mysql's log file but also /var/log/syslog since you may have had a server crash causing mysql to break down as a side effect.

Comment: Cor! Thank you! SELinux knocked out mysql-server, and I was going around in circles with no idea it happened and why nothing could connect

Comment: In /etc/my.cnf I dont have such file )))

Comment: for me it was in `etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` . It was the only file where `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` was present

Comment: Have same problem here and couldn't resolve it: https://serverfault.com/questions/1118742/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run/1118751#1118751

Answer (score 320):

Try this:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p <database>
```

Also (to see if it's running):

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
```

Probably it is just a misconfiguration in the `my.cnf` file, in `/etc/somewhere` (depending on the [Linux distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)).

Comment: I'm getting the same error. And I've checked and the default bind  in both the main and my.cnf is set to 127.0.0.1 already. However using your command above allowed me to connect. Will have to keep hunting to see why just doing "mysql" is giving the error.

Comment: I get telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused as a result of telnet command. However apache still runs as I'm able to open localhost

Comment: @cchiera You know, I didn't have this error before. But when I wanted to connect to my db thru an iOS app by using ssh tunnel, I got this 2013 error. To solve it I had to edit `/etc/my.cnf` and commented `#bind-address  = 127.0.0.1` [Reference 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38070979/1883256) [Reference 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19012220/1883256). Then I could connect. After this, I realized I was getting now this 2002 error which took me to this answer and now it's working again.Definitely I agree with you by getting an explanation about why just typing `mysql` without `-h` throws an error.

Comment: Note: `mysql -h localhost` does not work. Make sure to use `mysql -h 127.0.0.1` as specified in the answer.

Comment: How can I solve this if I get to login with the command in this answer?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This was my problem and I looked everywhere and none of the other solutions talked about this possibility

Comment: I am using mysql server on docker. localhost doesn't work, but 127.0.0.1 does.

Comment: why is this not accepted answer

Comment: @ViktorShvachuk thanks! That solved it for me!!

Answer (score 195):

I am seeing all these answers, but **none** offer the option to **reset the password** and **no accepted answer**. The actual question being he **forgot** his password, so he needs to reset, not see if it's running or not (installed or not) as most of these answers imply.

---

### To reset the password

Follow these steps (can be helpful if you really forget your password and you can try it anytime, even if you're not in the situation at the moment):

1. Stop `mysql`

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
   ```

   Or for other distribution versions:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
   ```
2. Start MySQL in safe mode

   ```
   sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
   ```
3. Log into MySQL using root

   ```
   mysql -u root
   ```
4. Select the MySQL database to use

   ```
   use mysql;
   ```
5. Reset the password

   ```
   -- MySQL version < 5.7
   update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';

   -- MySQL 5.7, mysql.user table "password" field -> "authentication_string"

   update user set authentication_string=password('mynewpassword') where user='root';
   ```
6. Flush the privileges

   ```
   flush privileges;
   ```
7. Restart the server

   ```
   quit
   ```
8. Stop and start the server again

   Ubuntu and Debian:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
   ...
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
   ```

On CentOS, Fedora, and RHEL:

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
    ...
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

9. Login with a new password

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```
10. Type the new password and enjoy your server again like nothing happened

This was taken from *[Reset a MySQL root password](https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password)*.

Comment: Updating the users password did not work for me however once logged into the MySQL monitor and having used the mysql database, `repair table user use_frm` worked for me to solve this problem. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297592/how-to-fix-error-130-hy000-incorrect-file-format

Comment: In MySQL 5.7, the password field in mysql.user table field was removed, now the field name is 'authentication_string', so (5) should be `update user set authentication_string=password('mynewpassword') where user='root';`

Comment: Would you know of a way to make this a bash script?  I seem to need it every time I restart the box.

Comment: Something tells me you want a workaround, but you should actually try to find out why you need to do this every time and fix that. As for the script ask a new question and post what you already tried, maybe some others could help

Comment: Not to be anal but, the OP did NOT ask how to change his password.  Here merely stated as a point of fact that he forgot it and when trying to change it, he encountered an error and directly after stating so, he asked "How can I fix this?" which strongly implied "how can I fix this error?"  Sorry, but reading comprehension counts.

Comment: This worked great for me, but I first had to implement this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153059/mysqld-safe-directory-var-run-mysqld-for-unix-socket-file-dont-exists

Comment: For MySQL 8, use the following for Step 5: UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';

Comment: @JoeKreydt, in v.8 it is also possible to use the original example for v.5.7+, however with the minor adaptation of providing the new password value without the surrounding `passowrd()` argument.

Comment: this does not work on Ubuntu

Comment: Amazing, this worked great for me! Thanks Andrewfox and davejal

Comment: For me I only had to stop and restart in safe mode, thanks!

Answer (score 77):

In my case it was that the disk was full and mysqld couldn't start anymore.

Try to restart mysql service.

```
> service mysql restart
```

or

```
> service mysql stop

> service mysql start
```

If it doesn't recognize `stop` command then it's definitely the disk space. You should make some space in the partition `mysql` is allocated or make the disk larger.

Check the disk space with

```
> df -h
```

Comment: The same thing happened to me - full disk. Cleaned up some space, rebooted and problem went away.

Comment: If that is your problem executing: "/etc/init.d/mysqld start" will tell you your disk partition is full

Comment: Same for me, disk 100%. Cleaned space and start service ok

Comment: Restarting mysql service worked for me, but I do not have disk space issues

Comment: When I try to restart I get this error:
```Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.```

Answer (score 75):

I tried the following steps:

1. Log in as `super user` or use `sudo`
2. Open `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` using [gedit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit)
3. Find `bind-address`, and change its value to the database server host machine's IP address. For me, it was `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
4. Save and close the file.
5. Come back to terminal and execute `sudo service mysql start`

And it worked for me.

Comment: From this, I just ran sudo service mysql restart and it worked.

Comment: In my case the error was the IP changed, so I set bind-address=localhost

Comment: @rshahriar there is nothing called as bind-address in my /etc/my.cnf is it a good idea to add the field

Comment: @SilvioDelgado Not if you ever want to connect through ssh tunneling. [Explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11061621)

Comment: restarting the mysql service worked for me as well, but still not sure where to find the error log in order to  figure out the cause and try to prevent it from happening again...

Answer (score 44):

I fixed this problem by executing the following command:

```
mysql.server start
```

And if you are on a mac and used brew to install mysql, simply use:

```
brew services start mysql
```

Answer (score 43):

I had a similar problem.  mysql wouldn't start:

```
sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start
```

If I disabled apparmor:

```
sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/*
```

the problem went away.  The issue was that mysqld was trying to access /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock but the apparmor profile only gave permission to /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (/var/run is symlinked to /run, so these are actually the same).  Not sure why mysqld isn't using the var path since that's what's set in all the configuration files, but you can fix the problem by adding the following to /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

```
/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock rw,
```

Comment: I didn't know that I had to call "sudo service mysql start". Last time I installed MySQL on Ubuntu, I think it autostarted upon installation. MariaDB on Manjaro requires the service to be explicitly started after installation.

Answer (score 32):

I solved this by killing the `mysql` process:

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
kill [the id]
```

And then I started the server again with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

But `start` works as well:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Then I logged in as `admin`, and I was done.

Comment: well, I actually was aborting mysql before it crashes. Then I get " * Please take a look at the syslog." and "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)". Finally, I realize it's trying to recover itself, so I kill and restart it.

Comment: There are (rare) situations where "mysql start" will fail, so you need to use the "restart" argument. If you need to kill a daemon process, its better to use the "stop" argument instead of the kill command. However, the killall command is more convenient than the kill command (killall mysqld).

Comment: Killing MySQL process and then restarting MySQL worked for me, nice

Answer (score 23):

Somehow the MySQL server process did not create the socket, or the client is looking for the socket in the wrong place.

My first suggestion would be to check if the MySQL server is running. Second suggestion might be, is the MySQL server running on another host? If so, add the `-h <hostname>` flag to your MySQL client in the terminal.

If MySQL is indeed running, and running locally, check your `my.cnf` file. There should be a line like

```
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

See if that matches the socket location that you mentioned in your post.

From experience, I would say the most likely scenario is your MySQL server either is not running at all or is not running on the same host as where you run your MySQL client from the terminal.

Answer (score 23):

I just experienced the same issue after I had to restart my production server. I am running Debian 8.1 (Jessie) on a DigitalOcean droplet.

This is what I did to resolve my issue:

1. Check if the file `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` exists. If it doesn't, manually create it by entering `touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` (which is what I had to do).
2. So the MySQL process can use this file. Change ownership of said file by entering `chown mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.
3. Once '2' has been done, restart the MySQL service by entering `service mysql restart` or `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`.

After going through the above steps, my issue was solved. I rarely have this issue, and there is probably a better way, so by all means provide constructive feedback if need be :).

Comment: I noticed the file was not there and just restarted the mysql server. It automatically created the file and started up just fine.
Thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 21):

Check the `"bind-adress"` parameter in my.cnf.

Else try with the command:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p
```

- -h for host `127.0.0.1`, that is, localhost
- -P (notice -P as uppercase) for port `3306`, that is, the default port for MySQL

Answer (score 15):

Your mysql-server might not be running. Ensure it runs by typing `mysql.server start` into the terminal.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using [Amazon EC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud), and you're having this problem on the instance, then you only need to do:

```
sudo yum install mysql-server
sudo service mysqld restart
```

Amazon EC2 doesn't have a server installed (only the client is installed), so in case of that you need to install that on your instance, and after that try

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

to check if that worked.

Comment: Failed to restart mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found. In Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 12):

I think whenever you get the error

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

I will recommend first to check whether your `mysql` daemon is running... Most of the time it will not running by default. You can check it by `/etc/init.d/mysqld status`.

If it's not running then start it first:

```
.../etc/init.d/mysqld start.
```

I bet it will 110% work.

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` is the correct solution also if you are using WSL since the upstart service is not supported: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/745

Comment: Same idea, but alternative syntax: `service mysqld start`

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using localhost:

```
mysql -u myuser -pmypassword -h localhost mydatabase
```

Use 127.0.0.1

```
mysql -u myuser -pmypassword -h 127.0.0.1 mydatabase
```

(also note, no space between -p and mypassword)

Enjoy :)

Comment: You can also not include your password from the command line for security by using this line:
mysql -u myuser -p -h 127.0.0.1 mydatabase
MySQL will ask you your password and not echo it.

Comment: This solved it for me. However, I still wonder why `127.0.0.1` works while `localhost` does not?!

Answer (score 12):

Fist,try to restart it with

> service mysql stop

> service mysql start

If above not resolve the issue, now let's go...

Uninstall completely MySQL

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\*
```

reinstall it

```
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
```

test if it run

```
sudo mysql
```

Install php drivers

```
sudo apt install php7.4 php7.4-fpm php7.4-mysql php7.4-cgi php7.4-cli php7.4-common
```

You can replace php7.4 by php7.x or php8.0.12 or later
Very nice !

❗️Be careful, you lose your data if they are not saved. Please backup your data if possible yet.

Comment: beware of data loss

Comment: this doesnt work . you even lose data

Comment: This solutions looks like a Windows issue fix, not a Linux.

Comment: Exactly, except at this time it worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 16 and 18. I haven't tested it on later versions.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have backups of important databases and then **try uninstall MySQL** related stuff:

```
apt-get remove --purge mysql\*
```

Then **install it again**:

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

This worked for me and data was kept.

If PHP MySQL shows errors you might have to **reinstall PHP MySQL**:

```
apt-get install php5-fpm php5-mysql
```

Comment: I think that's the fatal weapon.
I tried everything but, only your proposal is what helped me. Thank you !

Answer (score 11):

Here's what worked for me:

```
ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
service mysql restart
```

This creates a link.

Comment: Did not work for me :( This creats a symlink between the two folders http://askubuntu.com/a/56340/242873

Answer (score 10):

I also facing same problem it will be occur if your `mysql server` is not running by default it will again stop after some sec so you again run (`$ sudo service mysql start`  ) command you can change if know.

for that use command

```
$ sudo service mysql start
```

(put user password if required because we use `sudo` )
   and then run

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p          (put user password if required )
```

now you got your database

Answer (score 9):

I got this problem too, but I just did:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

It seems your MYSQL is stopped. use below command to start MySQL again

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) installed on your Linux machine, try to copy your `my.cnf` file from `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf` to `/etc/my.cnf`.

Then, run the `mysql -u root` again... You should now have the correct socket and be able to run the MySQL client.

Answer (score 8):

**I FOUND THE SOLUTION**

***Before firing*** the command : `mysql_secure_installation`

- Step 1: `sudo systemctl stop mariadb`
- Step 2: `sudo systemctl start mariadb`
- Step 3: `mysql_secure_installation`

Then it will ask root password and you can simply **press** ***Enter*** and set your new root password.

Answer (score 7):

If your installation was recent, you should to confirm if your installation is the installation SERVER... as mysql-server-5.5.. Maybe you installed only "mysql" .. this is only client instead of the server.

Answer (score 7):

On Debian server Jessie, my working solution was to simply do

```
service mysql restart
service mysql reload
```

as root user

Answer (score 7):

i solved this problem with restart mysql

`/etc/init.d/mysql stop`

and

`/etc/init.d/mysql start`

that's it.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the default port 3306 was being used by some other process and thus it was not starting. After I stopped the other service and did `sudo service mysql start`, it worked fine. BTW, you can use something like `sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP:3306` to see who may be using the port.

Answer (score 6):

Check if you have the correct rights:

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql/mysql
```

I had the same problems and this worked for me. After doing this I was able to start MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it worked by doing some R&D:

I am able to connect to MySQL using

```
root-debian#mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

But it's not working with `mysql -u root -p`.

I did not find any `bind-address` in *my.cnf*. So I outcommented the parameter `socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.sock` in `my.cnf` which was causing me a problem with login.

After restarting the service it went fine:

```
root@debian:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 5.6.19 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, It seems like I wasnt really able to kill the mysql process, when I run

```
sudo service mysql stop
ps -ef | grep mysql
```

The mysql process was always there, it looks like it was blocking the socket file and new mysql process wasnt able to create it itself.

so this helped

```
cd /var/run
sudo cp mysqld/ mysqld.bc -rf
sudo chown mysql:mysql mysqld.bc/
sudo service mysql stop
sudo cp mysqld.bc/ mysqld -rf
sudo chown mysql:mysql mysqld -R
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

Now Im able to log in database using

```
mysql -u root
```

Then to update root password:

```
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('YOURPASSWORDHERE') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**PS**: I had trouble updating root passwod, seems like problem with "auth_socket" plugin, so I had to create new user with full privileges

```
insert into user set `Host` = "localhost", `User` = "super", `plugin` = "mysql_native_password", `authentication_string` = NULL, `password_expired` = "N", `password_lifetime` = NULL, `account_locked` = "N", `Select_priv` = "Y",
`Insert_priv` = "Y", `Update_priv` = "Y", `Delete_priv` = "Y", `Create_priv` = "Y", `Drop_priv` = "Y", `Reload_priv` = "Y", `Shutdown_priv` = "Y", `Process_priv` = "Y", `File_priv` = "Y",
`Grant_priv` = "Y",  `References_priv` = "Y", `Index_priv` = "Y", `Alter_priv` = "Y", `Show_db_priv` = "Y", `Super_priv` = "Y", `Create_tmp_table_priv` = "Y", `Lock_tables_priv` = "Y",
`Execute_priv` = "Y", `Repl_slave_priv` = "Y",  `Repl_client_priv` = "Y",  `Create_view_priv` = "Y", `Show_view_priv` = "Y", `Create_routine_priv` = "Y", `Alter_routine_priv` = "Y",
`Create_user_priv` = "Y",  `Event_priv` = "Y", `Trigger_priv` = "Y", `Create_tablespace_priv` = "Y";
```

This creates user "super" with no password and then you can connect with `mysql -u super`

Comment: thanks for the answer and I able to log in to mysql, but there are no user table in my databases.

Comment: This solution works. But before you execute the sql statement to change the password for root, you need to select a database. Execute the following statement <br> `use mysql;` <br> and the you can now use <br> `UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('YOURPASSWORDHERE') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: To update root password for mysql8 use:
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_new_password_here';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;

Answer (score 6):

You are missing permission to create /var/run/mysqld directory.So please create and 
give permission as following.

- mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
- chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld

Comment: use sudo command

Answer (score 5):

By experience I say that you need to check if the server is running first and then try configuring MySQL. The last solution is to re-install MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

The same on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).

If you have installed XAMPP, installing mysql-server isn't the solution, because you'll access another MySQL!

You have to use the right socket to access. Usually it is this:

```
/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Instead, change it to:

```
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for XAMPP

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Sometimes this happens if your MySQL service is turned down.

So you have to start it:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 5):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.6

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5

sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Both MySQL database core client and MySQL Server packages will be the same version 5.5. MySQL Client 5.5 and MySQL Server 5.5 are the current "best" versions of these packages in Ubuntu 14.04 as determined by the package maintainers.

If you would rather install MySQL Client 5.6 and MySQL Server 5.6 you can also find the mysql-client-core-5.6 and mysql-server-5.6 packages in the Ubuntu Software Center. The important thing is that the client and server version numbers match in either case.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

```
mysqld stop
mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 5):

For CentOS Linux release 7.3
The mysql.sock file path is `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Edit `/etc/my.cnf` file and put below entry
This will solve your problem.

```
[client]
user=root
password=Passw0rd
port=3306
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

After this restart the service

```
service mysql restart
```

Comment: This answer actually explains what is the root cause for the error

Comment: This will not "solve" the problem, it's a workaround, and binding 0.0.0.0 exposes your local MySQL to, well, everyone

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. After much searching I didn't find any answer.

At last, I checked the `/tmp` directory, and its permissions were 755. I changed its permissions to 777 and mysqld started well without any problem.

Answer (score 4):

For me an update solved the problem:

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

On CentOS:

```
sudo yum update
```

Answer (score 4):

It works now...

I have followed the tutorial *[Installing MariaDB 10.1.16 on Mac OS X with Homebrew](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/installing-mariadb-10116-mac-os-x-homebrew)* to overcome this issue.

But don't forget to kill or uninstall the old installation of MariaDB.

Answer (score 4):

This issue happen because MySQL server was not started. check active status using below command.

```
service mysql status
```

If the active status is stop, then ry starting the MySQL server,

```
service mysql start
```

Answer (score 3):

Try restarting the server with

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

If there is any error then follow the below steps

1. `mysqld`

You will see the the below log. Notice the highlighted portion of the MySQL directory here

> mysqld: Can't change dir to
>   **'/usr/local/mysql-5.7.14-osx10.11-x86_64/data/'** (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied) 2016-10-04T14:09:19.392581Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP
>   with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use
>   --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 2016-10-04T14:09:19.392847Z 0 [Warning] Insecure
>   configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict
>   location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty
>   path. 2016-10-04T14:09:19.392921Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.14)
>   starting as process 1402 ... 2016-10-04T14:09:19.397569Z 0 [Warning]
>   Can't create test file 
>   /usr/local/mysql-5.7.14-osx10.11-x86_64/data/Sudharshan.lower-test 
>   2016-10-04T14:09:19.397597Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file
>   /usr/local/mysql-5.7.14-osx10.11-x86_64/data/Sudharshan.lower-test 
>   2016-10-04T14:09:19.397712Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to
>   /usr/local/mysql-5.7.14-osx10.11-x86_64/data/ 
>   2016-10-04T14:09:19.397776Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
>   
>   2016-10-04T14:09:19.397795Z 0 [Note] Binlog end 
>   2016-10-04T14:09:19.397925Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

2. `sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/mysql-5.7.14-osx10.11-x86_64`

Note the MySQL folder path ***/usr/local*** on the the previous log, and in my case it was ***mysql-5.7.14-osx10.11-x86_64***, and you have to ***update it based on the log you get*** on your machine to provide **read access** to the MySQL directory

3. `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

> Starting MySQL 
>   SUCCESS!

Answer (score 3):

I got exactely the same error when I have stopped mysql service, and here how to solve it: by (re)starting mysql using these commands:

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Comment: `sudo systemctl start mysql` worked for me as well on Lubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

Installing mysql-server solved the issue

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 3):

For me mysql wasn't running so I fixed it with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be silly to some extent. Like you forgot to start the server first. If you run the `mysql -u root -p` command before starting the server, you gonna get the same error.

Just start the server first

```html
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first check whether the service is running, with:

```
ps ax | grep mysql
```

I got this response:

```
6104 pts/0    S      0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
6431 pts/0    Sl     0:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/m
```

No response means the service isn't running, so do:

```
service  mysql start
```

Comment: Proper way to check that would be to do `sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld status` or `sudo service mysqld status`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was page corruption in all my databases (check the mysql error log).

I solved it with [Forcing InnoDB Recovery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html). The trick is editing /etc/mysql/my.cnf and adding

```
innodb_force_recovery = 4
```

just below

```
[mysqld]
```

And then restart mysql.
After checking everything works correctly now, remove the line back again.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy your `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf` file to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

And in the terminal type:

```
mysql -u root
```

You will be getting the `mysql>` prompt:

```
mysql> Update mysql.user set Password=PASSWORD('your_password') where user='root';

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Sudarsan. It is a Professional Q & A site. Please visit [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Although it is not wrong to do so but you are giving an answer to a question which was asked 2 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Install mysql-server:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
enter password as root
```

Login:

```
mysql -u root -p root
```

Here `-u user name` and `-p password` was given while installing MySQL server. It will work as it has worked for me.

Comment: Its about connecting mysql server using socket ,being used in PHP and languages like Ruby On Rails.

Answer (score 2):

My server storage was full, this was preventing Mysql from starting. Got the idea from [here](https://bobcares.com/blog/mysql-stop-unknown-instance/). Increasing the HD and rebooting fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I'm not able to access mysql and after 3 days research, I have got a solution. This is perfect solution because I have searched `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and I did not find the folder. You can run on putty the commands listed below.

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld/
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
sudo mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

You will save your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain it, but in kubuntu 12.04.2 after

> sudo apt-get autoremove linux-headers-3.2.0-37 linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic

it started to work

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ubuntu, it could be a matter of privileges.

Check your directory privileges. It's not enough to be in the root group, also use a [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) on directories which MySQL writes (for example, `/var/run/mysqld/` for the creation of the `mysqld.pid` file).

This was helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the problem from occurring, you must perform a graceful shutdown of the server from the command line rather than powering off the server.

```
shutdown -h now
```

This will stop the running services before powering down the machine.

Based on Centos, an additional method for getting it back up again when you run into this problem is to move mysql.sock:

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.bak

service mysqld start
```

Restarting the service creates a new entry called mqsql.sock

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem now and solved it.

Although you installed mysql-server, the daemon needs to be running in order for the client to connect to it.

First check to see if mysql server is running:

```
netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

You should see something like this:

```
$ sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*          LISTEN     6639/mysqld
```

If you don't have the server running, start the daemon by the following command:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

This should solve your problem if it's installed.

Answer (score 1):

You are running locally, meaning that your client runs on the same machine as your server.

Make sure that your Unix user can actually reach/read `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`:

```
ls -als /var
ls -als /var/run
ls -als /var/run/mysqld
ls -als /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

If not, check with your system administrator or [database administrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_administrator) to provide adequate read/execute access to those directories, or move the socket file elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Also check your `my.conf` (`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) and see if bind-address is set to 127.0.0.1.

If not, this might cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found this.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock’
```

This is because you are not running the `mysqld` daemon before launching the MySQL client. The file `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` will be automatically created upon running the first instance of MySQL.

To fix:

First start the MySQL daemon, then type `mysql`:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
mysql
```

#### Changing MySQL Root Password

By default, the root password is empty for the MySQL database. It is a good idea to change the MySQL root password to a new one from a security point of view.

```
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE user='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Once done, check by logging in:

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter Password: <your new password>
```

Comment: `Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]`
but still its when i run mysql `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is related to updating to MySQL 5.6 on machines with a small amount of RAM**

I had the same problem when upgrading from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6 on my Debian 8 (Jessie). MySQL was not started (the status was showing active/exited) and simply making `service mysql start` did not work, because as I found from the `/var/logs/mysql/error.log` log file:

```
InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(136019968 bytes) failed; errno 12
Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
```

The memory was not enough: I had only 256 MB of RAM.

In MySQL there is a setting, `performance_schema`. By default, it is turned off in MySQL 5.5.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema-startup-configuration.html

But in MySQL 5.6 the default is on, and simply by adding the following line in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and restarting, it worked.

```
performance_schema = off
```

**Warning:** Turning this setting off you might experience performance issues, but I guess in a development environment it won't be a problem.

Also, here is an article that might be helpful configuring MySQL to use minimal memory, *[Configuring MySQL to use minimal memory](http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html)* (web archive link in case the original link expires in the future https://web.archive.org/web/20201112041608/http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html).

Answer (score 1):

An advice: Always ask MySQL what the problem is. In my case, `less /var/log/mysql/error.log` and see this:

```
2015-07-28 12:01:48 23224 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log'
2015-07-28 12:01:48 23224 [ERROR] Aborting
```

It is complaining, because I uncommented this option in `my.cnf`, but after commenting this option, it started without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was:

Open `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or `/etc/my.cnf` and search for 'bind-address'. It was `127.0.0.1`. I converted it to localhost, so the line result should be 'bind-address = localhost'.

Otherwise, you should run the your MySQL server with an IP address that existed in the bind-address directive, i.e. `mysql -h 127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution on my server: After migrating to a new Debian 7 server with my MySQL databases, the second **local IP address**, `127.0.1.1`, was missing in my [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). Adding this resolved the warnings:

```
echo -e "\n127.0.1.1       $(hostname)" >> /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18:10 Linode 1GB Ram, I experienced this error. After examining /var/log/mysql/error.log , I came across this:

[Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

I upgraded my linode to 2GB and restarted mariadb with sudo mysql. Next mysql_secure_admin ran, but the root password did not set for the user-as ususl unitl changing the root user to use the mysql_native_password plugin.
Not sure, but it appears that the sock was created, but the server shutdown due to the lack of memory in my VPS.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i had files corrupted in my folder of mysql data

> mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_old

so as i had a backup, i moved the directory to "_old", and started the docker again. it created a new folder mysql with clean data, and the socket worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was missing mysql-server. So after installing it via `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` I was able to connect again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, on CentOS, I had to restart the `mariadb` service like this :

```
systemctl start mariadb.service
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case my problem was that I was trying to access from my linux terminal, and not from my docker container with the mysql.

Answer (score 1):

If your server/db was working fine and suddenly this issue appear, then just try restarting your db server.
For Centos i do with below command and my issue 'connection refused' 'Cann't connect to local mysql through socket' fixed

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

Comment: I used `service mariadb start`

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that your bind-address is set to 'localhost'. This issue could arise from a misconfiguration where the bind-address is not properly set.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing this line from my `/etc/mysql/my.conf` in the `mysqld` section ([mysqld]):

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

Restart and it works fine.

Comment: What does character encoding has to do with password?

Comment: @Moslem This problem is not always about password, nor InnoDB. I have not set password and not using InnoDB (skip-innodb) and got same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify the owner of the group for `/var/run/mysqld`. If it isn't `mysql.mysql`, then do:

```
su root
chown mysql.mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading MySQL fixed it for me.  On RHEL-based servers, just run:

```
sudo yum upgrade mysql-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if LAMPP is running?

```
sudo bash <path>/lampp start
```

For me, path is

```
sudo bash /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with the configuration file. I had a similar problem, and I couldn't find a solution on the web. I noticed that I had two `my.cnf` files, one in `/etc/mysql` and the other in `/etc`.
Follow the steps below:

1. Check for `my.cnf` files on your computer using `locate my.cnf`.
2. If there are two entries, i.e. `/etc/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`,
   rename `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to something else, e.g `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.old`

Try to run MySQL again.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo touch /var/lib/mysql/.force_upgrade
sudo rcmysql restart
```

worked for me when I had this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this on Ubuntu and as I've figured out, there was more than one instance of mysqld.

It looked like the previous one had not been completely stopped, while the new one has already started. Running '/etc/init.d/mysql stop' didn't help, it was always returning 'OK' and a new instance has been launched automatically immediately after that:

```
        $ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
         * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld        [ OK ] 
        $ pgrep mysql
        28315
        $ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
         * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld        [ OK ] 
        $ pgrep mysql
        28570
        $ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
         * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld        [ OK ] 
        $ pgrep mysql
        28763
        ..... etc ...
```

Fortunately, the following command has fixed the problem:

```
    $ sudo service mysql stop
    mysql stop/waiting

    $ ps -ef | grep mysql
    29841 26858  0 10:59 pts/8    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql <--- IT's gone !
```

After that I was able to start mysql again and see that mysql.sock has been successfully created.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, check the last line be:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: You should an some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too and neither of these answers helped me. The issue was different, but the error was the described by the OP.

I check the logs of MySQL in `/var/log/mysql`, and I saw this:

```
150309  5:03:19 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable   'lower_case_tables_names=1'
```

I opened the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and outcommented that line `#`. After doing that, I was able to connect to the database.

Honestly I don't know what the problem was. The linode server was scheduled to restart due to maintenance, and this error came out of nowhere.

Comment: What is "linode server"? Do you mean "Linux server"?

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you try to change the directory where the database is stored, but imput the wrong directory in the configuration file (like a typo in the second drive as `D` instead of the accurate `D_`). Instead of telling you the typo directory does not exist, it will tell you that you lack permission to access it (leading you to try to change the permissions for the typo directory, which it will let you do). So if you get this error while changing directories, double check the configuration file and make sure you don't have a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I had to say:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Answer (score 0):

I my case it was just because mysql was stopped because of the missing `/var/log/mysql` folder defined in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. After creating it I could start mysql and it ran as usual.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is likely to drown here, but maybe somebody stumbles upon it accidentally.

In my case, SELinux prevented the user/application from connecting to the MySQL (MariaDB) server socket. On RHEL, check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` if you have SELinux enabled.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION 1
Purge out (or remove if you want to keep databases) any mysql packages to repeat the installation anew:

```
sudo apt purge "mysql*"
```

-Autoremove packages

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

-Stop the apparmor service

```
sudo systemctl stop apparmor
```

-Make apparmor drop its profiles (I thought with stop it was enough, but for me it wasn't. With systemctl it doesn't work)

```
sudo service apparmor teardown
```

-Reinstall mysql-server

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

-Install apparmor-utils, to create a profile for mysql in apparmor that allows mysql to run

```
sudo apt install apparmor-utils
```

-Check the status of mysql-server (must be Active(running))

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
```

-Generate a profile for mysql in apparmor

```
sudo aa-genprof mysql
```

-In other terminal run mysql (enter root password)

```
mysql -u root -p
```

-do things in MySQL while apparmor is generating the profile in the other terminal

> mysql> CREATE DATABASE fooDB

-Swith to the other terminal and press "s" (the prompt tells you it's for "scan")

-Say yes to the policies from apparmor you see fit (I guess all of them for mysql), say yes pressing "a" for Allow

-Press "f" to Finish the apparmor profile

-Restart the apparmor service

```
sudo systemctl start apparmor
```

-Check to see if you still can use mysql in the other terminal

> mysql>exit

```
mysql -u root -p
```

If all is well you can use mysql from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this issue, surprisingly, is the deletion of the folder /var/log/mariadb
This was my case after i deleted this log folder. After the creation, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had previously this problem in Kubuntu 20.04. How It solved for me was to just run:

```sh
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

The cause was that dpkg had crashed.

I had the problem other time, and I solved it by running:

```sh
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Think the service was stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and the problem was that mysql-server was installed but it was not running.

Try,
service mysql start
Or
systemctl start mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can check the logs /var/log/mysql.log

for me it was not working bcs of this error:

Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool error

I added this line in /etc/my.cnf and started service:

innodb_buffer_pool_size=100M

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue in termux for mariadb, which resolved my issue is these following two lines of command -

`pkill mysql`

`mysqld_safe -u root`

Comment: use "sudo pkill mysql"  if there is error for "failed: Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. For me, I loaded a snapshot of Garuda Linux and I haven't restored it and thus getting the mentioned error.

The fix for this is to restore the snapshot. Once it's done everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

***WordPress users take note -*** all of these answers refer to a non-running or failing MySQL or MariaDB install and when using WordPress that can mean that you just updated a Plugin and it caused the database to fail.  The fix, in that case, is to disable the offending Plugin and (sometimes needed) restart the server.  In your wp-content/plugins folder (you can get there in a command line, with FTP like FileZilla, or with the Files function on your cPanel) you will find all of the plugins.  You can rename the offending one and it will be automatically disabled in WordPress.  You can rename them all (or remove them to another folder) and this will disable all of them so that you can move them in one at a time to find the one that is killing your MySQL if you have no idea what the offending plugin is.  All of your plugin settings are stored in the database, so you will not lose anything by disabling them (as long as you move the plugin back in the plugins folder or rename it the way it was).  Once MySQL is not being clobbered anymore the database will be available and you will not have to do any reinstall (other than perhaps to go back to the previous version of the offending plugin).

Answer (score -1):

You could resolve the issue by using the following commands

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP /var/lib/mysql
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP /var/log/mysql
```