# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm getting this error

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock' (2)`

even though I have managed to start mysql via command line in ubuntu

```
mysql stop/waiting
mysql start/running, process 17691
```

However when attempting to access the site I get a database connection error as well as the above error when trying to access mysql via `mysql -u root -p`

I checked my error logs and I saw this

```
    131029 12:53:34 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be remo$
    131029 12:53:34 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    131029 12:53:34 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    131029 12:53:34 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    131029 12:53:34 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
    131029 12:53:34 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 26.0G
    131029 12:53:36 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    131029 12:53:36 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    131029 12:53:38  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
    131029 12:53:39 InnoDB: 5.5.34 started; log sequence number 5146431500
    131029 12:53:39 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
    131029 12:53:39 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
    131029 12:53:39 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
    131029 12:53:39 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    131029 12:53:39 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
    Version: '5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

It's the first time I see this error and I'm not sure how to solve this issue, please help me out a bit here.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Okay I tried glglgl's solution and after a restart, I get the following in the error log:

```
    131029 13:17:36 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be remo$
    131029 13:17:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    131029 13:17:36 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    131029 13:17:36 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    131029 13:17:36 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
    131029 13:17:36 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 26.0G
    131029 13:17:38 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    131029 13:17:38 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    131029 13:17:40  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
    131029 13:17:41 InnoDB: 5.5.34 started; log sequence number 5146431500
    131029 13:17:41 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
    131029 13:17:41 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
    131029 13:17:41 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.  
    131029 13:17:41 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    131029 13:17:41 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
    Version: '5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Look on the right,in the related column.

Comment: I did, for almost a week. None of the solutions there helped me and I've tried them all

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Comment: I don't think this question appropriate for stackoverflow and must be moved to http://serverfault.com/. On the other hand RTFM; MySQL installation procedure on Ubuntu is described in details a lot of times (include troubleshooting procedures), just don't be lazy and google it

Comment: There is a working solution in this thread: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,561011,561282#msg-561282

Comment: Duplicate and bad answers, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/

Answer (score 66):

My problem was solved checking if the process was running on Ubuntu 12.04

```
ps ax | grep mysql
```

Then the answer was that it wasn't running, so I did

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Or try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: it says unrecognized service!

Comment: Try sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` helped me. Thank you

Comment: there's no mysql in etc/init.d!

Comment: This helped me sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Answer (score 52):

Firstly, please confirm mysql-server is installed. I have the same error when mysql-server is installed but corrupted somehow. I do the trick by uninstall mysql **completely** and reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Comment: after updating ubuntu my installation got corrupted; clean installation gave me confidence

Comment: this worked for me although the first three commands for cleaning where not necessary

Answer (score 17):

This took me ages to figure out but could you try the same -

1 - Update and Upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

2 - Purge MySQL Server and Client (if installed).

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client
```

3 - Install MySQL Server and Client fresh

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

4 - Test MySQL

```
mysql -u root -p
> enter root password
```

*** should get socket not found in /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock

4 - Configure mysqld.cnf with nano of vi

sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Change bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to localhost

```
bind-address            = localhost
```

** Write and Exit

5 - Restart MySQL

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

6 - check mysql

```
mysql -u root -p
> enter root password

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

You should get in to mysql cli now.

Hope this helps

Code.Ph0y

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem when i installed xampp on my system. The mysql server looks for /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock but the mysql.sock file was in xampp folder so i used

```
 find / -name '*.sock'
```

to find the mysql.sock file and then used

```
ln -s <the file location> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

to get a link for the *.sock file then tried mysql and it ran without error.
Hope this could solve yours.

**Remember to create the directory if it does not exists.**

Comment: Also should use sudo when access denied (for creating the folder and the symbolic link)

Answer (score 13):

The client should be set consistent with server setting.

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
```

Comment: What server setting? Where? Is this a file that needs editing, or should this be pre-set? Explanation please.

Comment: @DaveWalley I assume he is referring to the [my.cnf file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html)

Comment: Sure, and usually it's located in /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Answer (score 12):

**You don't need to reinstall MySQL server**
I was facing the same issue but I have resolved the issue by running these commands.

1. `ps -A|grep mysql`
2. `sudo pkill mysql`
3. `ps -A|grep mysqld`
4. `sudo pkill mysqld`
5. `sudo service mysql restart`
6. `sudo mysql -u root -p`

Comment: 6.`mysql -u root-p`  this step should be with root privilege like `sudo mysql -u root-p`

Comment: Yes, you are right @KasunHasanga, I have updated it

Answer (score 7):

recently i have faced with this error in my mysql
`ERROR 2002 (HY000)`:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>
> '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)

because i forget to start my mariadb.
just type this command on ur terminal.

```
systemctl start mariadb.service
```

Answer (score 6):

In the linux terminal, I run the following steps and they helped me out

1.First of all list all the mysql packages installed

```
  sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

2.Delete the listed packages  with the listed command

```
  sudo apt-get --purge autoremove <package name>
```

3.Reinstall mysql server

```
  sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

This worked for me, Hope this works for you aswell.

Alternatively Try

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-\
```

then reinstall with

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Answer (score 5):

I deleted everything connected to mysql with

> sudo apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7
>
> sudo rm -r /etc/mysql* /var/lib/mysql* /var/log/mysql*

and then reinstalled it again with

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

and then started it with

> mysql -u root -p

followed by the password

Answer (score 3):

I have follow **Wellington Lorindo** posting.
And My problem was solved.

***Steps***
1. run in terminal

> ps ax | grep mysql

**Result was**

11200 ?        Ssl    0:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld

11514 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep mysql

***Steps*** 
2. Again type this

> sudo service mysql start

And problem solved.

Thanks **Wellington Lorindo**

Answer (score 3):

You may be missing mysql-server. install it using

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: "even though I have managed to start mysql via command line in ubuntu"

Answer (score 3):

This is an old tread with different solution proposed, but none of them worked for me. I'm adding this answer in the hope it will help somebody who struggled as me for some time.

I've checked all the existing answers and all the existing solution, but for me the issue was incorrect user permission on `var/run/mysql` folder.

I've checked the user permission on that folder and it was set to `root`. Once i changed to `mysql:mysql` the problem has gone.

So enter into `/var/run/mysqld` and change the user permission to:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql .
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem.

This process worked for me:

> Ensure that during remove process you choose **No** to deleting database.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look close, you'll see the difference:

- The server listens on `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`
- The client tries to connect to `/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock`

You'll have to adjust the one or the other.

Comment: I'm able to access the website and access the database but I can't access it via command line, still gets the same error

Comment: how adjust to mysql?

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo By editing the config files involved to point to the same file.

Comment: not sure how, need your [assist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66672536/2368696)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after altering my.cnf. I resolved this problem next steps.

First : to find the location of error.log, look at 'my.conf'.

Second : I looked up error.log, I found next massages,

"unknown variable 'default-......' "
.....
" mysqld_safe Starting mysqld darmon with from /var/lib/mysql "

Third : I reset my.conf to the default, then restart, this problem was resolved.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The same error occured with my system as well. I had to remove mysql-server and reinstall it. Not other way around. Try running these commands it it works:

1. sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
2. sudo apt-get autoremove
3. sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

first i tried this, but i dont understand why it doesn't work this way

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 2):

**On Debian** this was a bind problem for me so changing `bind-address` from `localhost` to 0.0.0.0 helped.

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

`bind-address            = 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Faced the same on Ubuntu, our service team has moved the server and changed the IP address and MySQL started to fail after turning the machine on. I have updated the IP address in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and then did `/etc/init.d/mysql start` as most of the answers suggest here.

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem. 
`mysql -u root -p`
Enter password: 
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)`

Then I find the reason is my `selinux` is enforcing, I disable it then restart `mysqld` , it works, hope helpful.

Comment: Which Distro of linux were you running? You mention selinux so I am guessing CentOS .... I am running Ubuntu and experiencing the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

There is another chance of you to get this particular error if you modify the `max_connections` in `my.cnf` file.

I also faced the same error which did not let me log in to MySQL server. In my case the problem was, I had to increase the `max_connections` size in

> /etc/mysql/my.cnf

to

```
set-variable = max_connections = 5000
```

Due to this reason next day when I stared MySQL server it threw this error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Removing the `set-variable = max_connections = 5000` segment from `my.conf` file did the trick. After removing that particular segment following **command** was used. MySQL server started up and running like previously.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem will occurred due to some unnecessary changes made in my.cnf file.
Try to diff `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` with one of working mysql servers my.cnf file.

I just replaced `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file with new my.cnf file and this works for me.

Comment: life saving option, thanks

Comment: i just delete `rm /etc/mysq/my.cnf` and eveyting works fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-{version_number}
```

`version_number` should be mysql version number. For example

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.6
```

Then access mysql like this:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using wsl on windows 10 with ubuntu you can run:

- `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`
  the command `sudo service start mysql` wont work because you need to configure it. You can find how [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mysql.server.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Two main reasons:

1) mysql-server isn't installed! You have to install it (mysql-server and not mysql-client) and run it.

2) It's installed by default and running. So, it's not possible to run it again through Xampp or Lampp. You have to stop it:
sudo service mysql stop

then you can start it through Xampp.
It's possible to check if it's running or not with this code:
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql

If you see a result like this:
tcp    0      0 localhost:mysql       *:*        LISTEN      1043/mysqld

It means that it's running properly.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the bind address configuration option in the my.cnf file in /etc/ is the same with localhost or virtual serve ip address.
plus check to make sure that the directory for creating the socket file is well specified.

Answer (score 0):

This provides an alternative solution if the issue relates to you. If your disk drive is full than the MYSQL server (and most other programmes) is unable to start. Delete files and folders to allow Mysql-server to start up.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:
run these codes:::

```
 1:: ls -lart/var/run/my*

   2::mkdir /var/run/mysqld

    3::touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    4:ls -lart /var/run/mysqld
    5::chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld
    6::ls -lart /var/run/mysqld
REstart your mysql server
```

then finaly type mysql -u root or mysql -u root -p and press enter key. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had added "default-character-set=utf8" to my.cnf and that was corrupting the file. Instead change that line for "character_set_server=utf8". That should solve it, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I ran into this trouble after I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 distribution using `apt-get upgrade`. I had to completely purge `mysql-server` and `mysql-client` and reinstall it to fix this issue.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this error too, and it took almost 3 hours to find it.

First of all, try to recall the changes that you made to your conf file, then undo the changes and save the file and start mysql. If you want to make any changes to the conf file, then stop mysql server and then change the desired values and restart mysql.

This error occurs because of an incorrect (wrong keyword or wrong value assigned) change made to the conf file. Most of the times this error occurs even if you restart the machine running the server, as the server is stopped, in that case, start mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and tried all the solutions posted here like :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove mysql-server
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work for me on ubuntu 16.04. To uninstall the right package you need to  :

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-
```

when you tried to autocomplete using `tab` the command it will list the following package :

```
mysql-client           mysql-client-core-5.7  mysql-server           mysql-server-core-5.7  mysql-workbench        mythes-en-us           
mysql-client-5.7       mysql-common           mysql-server-5.7       mysql-utilities        mysql-workbench-data
```

obviously choose the `mysql-server-core-5.7` so it would be :

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server-core-5.7
```

and now you can uninstall all mysql and reinstall again using these command from [johnny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36515713/2652524) :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Now I solved it and the Error is GONE.

Answer (score 0):

Once you install or update MySQL, it won't ask you to create the root password. In that case: you will have file called "*debian.cnf*" path: */etc/mysql*. You will find user name and password, login with that credentials and create new user and password.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the mysql log in the `cd /var/lib/mysql` directory in the `mysql-error.log` file with the command `tail -n 200 mysql-error.log` and identified (**`[ERROR]`**) that there were two **wrong variables** in **my.ini**, after I removed them I was able to start the mysql service with the command `/etc/init.d/mysql start` or `service mysql start`

Answer (score 0):

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock' (2)

I get the error above when I try to log into MYSQL after installing it using brew, I am running MacOs, Oh yea I also noticed mysql is running I have restarted numerous times with no luck resolving the issue along with removing mysql and numerous reinstalls!

So simple I could slap myself, no but really, I solved this by CD into the temp folder that contains mysqlx.sock and mysql.sock.lock files, I deleted the single sock.lock file only and this solved my issue after doing so and I can log into mysql using the mysql -uroot command. Here are the commands I used. (this issue had me hung up for a while)

```
~ cd /tmp 

/tmp ls
```

(this will list all the sock files in the temp folder, output shown below)

```
com.apple.launchd.8AgGW2s9Bb mysql.sock.lock
com.apple.launchd.batxrSISAJ mysqlx.sock
com.apple.launchd.cRCaxtT41m mysqlx.sock.lock
com.google.Keystone          powerlog
```

then run

```
rm -R mysql.sock.lock
```

(use command above to remove the sock.lock file from the /tmp directory this resolved my issue)

hope this helped :)

Answer (score -1):

You must do:

```
ls -lart /var/run/mysqld/
mkdir /var/run/mysqld
touch /var/run/mysqld/myssqld.sock
ls -lart /var/run/mysqld/
chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld/
ls -lart /var/run/mysqld/
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Then access like so:

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> show databases;
```

Answer (score -4):

```
rm -rf mysql.sock
```

service mysqld restart