# Cannot open MySQL for the first time

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server

I have installed MySQL from Ubuntu software center, MySQL client and MySQL workbench as well.

the problem is I cannot do anything but to call `sudo mysql start` and `sudo mysql stop`

when i try to run the following command `sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation` i am prompted to enter the root password, i didn't set the root password so i just clicked 'Enter'

I got the following

> > ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I went to `/var/run/mysqld` and i have found that it is completely empty.

#### Update

I don't know if that would help, but I have tried to find the PID file by using `find / -type f -name "*.pid"` command . I haven't found any files related to mysql with the extension `.pid`

Comment: Are you sure you installed your MySQL?

Comment: try:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password/16556534#16556534

Comment: yes and when i run the command **service mysql status
**  
it returns 

>> mysql start/post-start, process 14029
 post-start process 14030

Comment: Try to change or reset your root password on MySQL. Try my link above

Comment: I have followed the instructions in there . in the second command ** sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &** I got the following
141209 10:23:43 [ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys' @ChristianMark

I tried to open the file but i got a message saying wrong formate !

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658891/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: @Maged I did. The problem there was they didn't start the server or the socket file is misplaced. in my case , there is no socket file fourn related to mysql from the begining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was removing the installation without sufficient commands, as it seems, finally i have removed it using the following :

```
#sudo service mysql stop  
#sudo killall -9 mysql
#sudo killall -9 mysqld
#sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
#sudo apt-get autoremove
#sudo apt-get autoclean
#sudo deluser mysql
#sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
#sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-core-5.5
#sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.5
```

This time i have removed the user as well. I didn't know that would matter. anyway after reinstalling it again it worked just fine