# Resetting MySQL password & missing mysqld.sock file

Tags: mysql, sockets

I am trying to run a local mysql server, on my own computer. I have lost the password that I initially set up. When I try to connect to mysql, I get the following error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I have therefore tried [these steps](https://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/) to reset my MySQL password, but the line

> mysql -u root mysql

returns the same error message:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

When running the command

> mysqladmin -u root -p status
> I get the following message:
> error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
>
> Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

I have been checking and the file mentioned (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock) doesn't actually exist. I am not sure what is causing this.

I have tried a couple of solutions online including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658891/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38) but none of this solutions worked for me. I would like to add that mysql-server is installed on my machine.

Any help appreciated. Please accept my apologies if there is any confusion to the above statements. I tried to explain what is happening as much as I can, but I am a beginner and I am clueless as to what is happenening there.

Comment: Looks like MySQL server is not running.

Comment: Try starting it with these commands... https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/start-stop-mysql-from-the-command-line-terminal-osx-linux/

Comment: you may follow this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Comment: @FredericoFalcao Thanks, however from my understanding, the line "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop" would indeed stop the server, which is required to reset the password. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @HareshKumar I tried this solution yesterday, it didn't work. The lines 1 to 4 on the first solution presented worked fine (I only had to replace "password" by "authentication_string" as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692812/mysql-user-db-does-not-have-password-columns-installing-mysql-on-osx) but I still have the problem today.

Comment: @HareshKumar I have also tried their "last resort" solution, and the line

`mysqladmin -u root password your-new-password`

results in

`mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed`

`error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Stop the mysql demon process using this command :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

2) Start the mysqld demon process using the --skip-grant-tables option with this command

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

> Because you are not checking user privs at this point, it's safest to
>   disable networking. In Dapper, /usr/bin/mysqld... did not work.
>   However, mysqld --skip-grant-tables did.

1) start the mysql client process using this command

```
mysql -u root
```

2) from the mysql prompt execute this command to be able to change any password

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

3) Then reset/update your password

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

4) If you have a mysql root account that can connect from everywhere, you should also do:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
```

once have received a message indicating a successful query (one or more rows affected), flush privileges:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then stop the mysqld process and relaunch it with the classical way:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

This is borrowed from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset , you can check also another method to reset mysql password.

Comment: After perform steps 1-4 you need to execute `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` and restart mysql daemon.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this approach, but after `mysql -u root` I get the error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` which I can't resolve.

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-N.N` where N.N is mysql-server version

Comment: I tried the purge solution but the line `mysqladmin -u root password your-new-password` won't run: `mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed`
`error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'`. As for `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-N.N` (my version is 5.7), it doesn't seem to help. I get `Checking if update is needed.`
`This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.12, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade`

Comment: try with this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server

Comment: That last link fixed it! It looks like I had my.cnf files all over the place. Doing that step by step fixed it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115950/discussion-between-pauline-and-haresh-kumar).

Comment: I think the OP is following a similar step-by-step, and during `sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &` I get the error about the socket...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your MySQL server is not running at all.
Can you check it?

```
service mysql status
```

You need to try restart it and make sure that you can stop and start it using

```
service mysql stop
service mysql start
```

If you have any errors post them here please.

Comment: How does this answer differ from the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling mysql-server worked for me. (I am using mysql 5.7)

```
sudo wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
mysql_secure_installation
```

Answer (score 0):

first kill user

```
sudo pkill -u <user>
```

Then install mysql server

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Configure it

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Enter into mysql shell

```
sudo mysql
```