# "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)" getting this on aws linux (centos)

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to install mysql for the first time on aws linux instance running the following commands

```
sudo yum install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

As soon as I run the second command I get

```
In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
Enter current password for root (enter for none):
```

And I haven't even set my root password. How am I supposed to enter a password which I haven't set in the first place?

Comment: I think earlier there was mysql installed on this machine which has not been removed completely

Comment: Try this http://www.zyxware.com/articles/5098/solved-what-are-the-steps-to-reinstall-mysql-server-using-ubuntu-terminal

Comment: An hidden file `.mysql_secret` would have been created under the home directory of the user who installed it. This will contain the default password for you to use for changing the password.

Comment: Please review this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658891/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: @sprksh already did that. Still get exact same thing even after reinstalling "enter current password"

Comment: @user3576036 did you get a solution? I am actually facing the same problem on an ubuntu server

Comment: @sprksh On ubuntu? It actually worked for me on Ubuntu. I didn't have much time to try anymore solutions on Centos so I switched to a new Ubuntu 14.04 EC2 instance on aws. And I ran `sudo apt-get update`
and `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. As soon as you run the second command a blue screen will be prompted to set a new root password to you Mysql. You can take it from there.

Comment: @user3576036 yes, on ubuntu 14.04, I am facing the same problem. actually few of my tables were corrupted and I planned to upgrade to 5.7 and recreate the db from dump and yes I was able to install but the earlier version of mysql is not being completely removed and as i create the database in 5.7, the same problem comes up. Anyway I will try more things :)

Answer (score 0):

----List installed mysql

```
sudo yum list installed | grep mysql
```

----Remove all

```
sudo yum remove mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common mysql-devel
```

delete some conf files manually :

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
sudo rm -rf /etc/my.cnf
```

Try to reinstall

```
sudo yum install mysql mysql-server
```

get the autogenerated password

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log

mysql -uroot -p
```

use the autogen password

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass4!';
```

Hope it solve your problem .

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

Comment: I followed your exact instruction I removed all those but sorry it didn't work. I tried installing it on another ec2 instance with ubuntu system. There the system prompts us something like "set root password for sql"  during the installation itself. I dont know what is wrong with Centos system. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3576036 actually centos create a autogenerated password 

after installation step try 
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log

you will get the password . now  you can alter yyour password with desired one

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';