# Resetting mysql password results: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu

I keep getting the error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

When trying to connect to MySQL via terminal.

I've done both tutorials:

The official one: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

and a less official one: 
https://coderwall.com/p/j9btlg/reset-the-mysql-5-7-root-password-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Creating the file `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` actually works after giving it permissions `chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld` `chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and then I can log in to mysql in the terminal and change my main user and root users the password.

After running `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` or `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` I again - cannot connect to mysql using my user names and passwords.

```
service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-05-07 12:00:51 IDT; 43s ago
  Process: 11057 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11042 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11056 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 13 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 103.3M
      CPU: 464ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─11056 /usr/sbin/mysqld

May 07 12:00:20 asd systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
May 07 12:00:51 asd systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Following this post: 
[ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658891/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Restarting mysql didn't work as mentioning at the begging of the post when running `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` again results:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.servicejob-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
[ ok job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
.
sudo service mysql start
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
```

completely reinstalling MySQL isn't acceptable.

One of the commenters said:

> The client should be set consistent with server setting.
>
> ```
> [client]
> port        = 3306
> socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>
> [mysqld]
> user        = mysql
> pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
> socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
> port        = 3306
> ```

which is weird because in my directory  `/var/run/mysqld/` the `mysqld.sock` file gets somehow deleted and don't have anything that looks like this in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

How do i stable my MySQL login properly? 
Why is this happening?

Running:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

Answer (score 0):

In termux while using PHP v8.1.3 and MariaDB 10.6.4 l faced the same issue and l tried : telnet 127.0.0.1 3306 and l received the following response:

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

And l knew that MySQL sever was not running and went further to run the following:

> $PREFIX/etc/init.d/mysql stop

And received the following response:

> ERROR! MariaDB server process #9102 is not running!

And l knew the problem is l haven't started the MySQL service which you may start as follows:

> $PREFIX/etc/init.d/mysql start

In termux

Or

> sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

In Ubuntu

The response from termux is

```
Starting MariaDB.


220318 11:44:24 mysqld_safe Logging to '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/mysql/localhost.err'.
220318 11:44:25 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/mysql.
 SUCCESS!
```

Good lucky!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Are you still facing this issue? probably not but something similar happened to me and I realized that while the query was running OK, it was not affecting any rows...I modified the query to match only 'localhost' and that worked:

UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';

Comment: Your answer is not relevant to the question asked.

Comment: It's resolved but not by me, so I don't have much info. The sysadmin told me it had something to do with `--skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &` and mysql not able to communicate. so try re-enabling  `--skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &` and restart mysql. If you figure this out, please post it here so others can enjoy.