# debian, mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000), phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

starting mysql with -u show:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

while full [error log](https://gist.github.com/sukrosono/8f24842da62e66d28a805a48906fbd9a)
show :

```
[ERROR] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'innodb_file_format=Barracuda'.
2021-03-17T11:40:17.721854Z 0 
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

apt list [result](https://gist.github.com/sukrosono/0dce11d76ec30da715103b342a452a7b)

this happens after I upgrade to MySQL 8. somehow this persist, if it was possible i won't reinstall MySQL. I expect I can log in on phpmyadmin, but I know it's not his problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mysql [v8.0.0 release note](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-0.html#mysqld-8-0-0-feature) says:

> The following InnoDB file format configuration options were deprecated in MySQL 5.7.7 and are now removed:

> innodb_file_format

You need to remove this option from your configuration file as it is no longer available in mysql v8.

Comment: yes it does make MySQL service running, could you help me move the q to serverfault?