# How to solve Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket error in ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Getting the below error while connecting MySQL

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

The `/var/run/mysqld` folder is showing as empty. How can I create `mysqld.sock` file inside the `mysqld` folder and what are the configurations I need to include it.

PS: I already perform uninstall and reinstall operations several times. But it also don't workout.

I referred the below links for solve this issue. But it doesn't work.

- [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)
- [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658891/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/997531/error-mysql-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-soc

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Usually mysql error logs which is under /var/log/mysqld/error.log will show you the cause. this issue usually points to mysql-server not running even a single time.