# MySql ERROR 2002

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

i have install mysql in my server {ubuntu 12.04 LTS} and it's work great

but now all my database is down and when  i run in termeanl {mysql} it's give this error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

and when i try to start mysql it's give that error {service mysqld start}

```
mysqld: unrecognized service
```

i dont need to lose my data so i dont make anything in the server, can you please help me?

Comment: There are lots and lots of links for troubleshooting this error.  For example: [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Comment: Did you also try to start it through `/etc/init.d/apache`???

Comment: @paulsm4 it's not same issue

Comment: @Mathlight it's work now when i run this command 
/etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: @csbukhari, glad i could help. I will post it as an answer so that you can check this question as answerd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i menthoid [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646230/mysql-error-2002#comment30907437_20646230), there are many ways to rome. I did mention apache, but as you figured out, the correct term was `mysqld`.

So instead of the command `start mysql`, you can also use `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots and lots of links for troubleshooting this error.  For example:

- [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

In your case "111" is connect error - you simply don't have the mySql server running.

So the *real* problem is getting "service mysqld start" to work.

Suggestion: try reinstalling:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/361614/mysqld-unrecognized-service
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/mysqld-unrecognized-service-4175432133/

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the same issue, i try to make it run with  service mysqld start..

Comment: It's *exactly* the issue.  The "error 2002" is a red herring because the service won't start (I/O error 111: connection refused).  The goal is to figure out why it isn't starting.  Then make it start automatically.

Comment: @csbukhari, i must agree with paylsm4. The `/etc/...` thing is just a work around. You've got to find out why it isn't starting normal. ( so you better start reading all the apache log files, mysql log files and system log files and try to see where an error occurs