# ERROR 2002 (HY000) on installing moodle on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, installation, mysql.sock

I follow the steps in:
http://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Step-by-step_Install_Guide_for_Ubuntu

and in step 6, after typing the following command :

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I have this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

And when I go to the '`/var/run/mysqld` I can't found **mysqld.sock** although in file(`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`)the :

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
```

So why this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following the installation instruction for Apache/MySql/PHP at :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Basically

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Then follow the instructions for installing Moodle

http://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Installing_Moodle