# Can't connect to Database-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I know this question has been asked many times, but in all other posts i searched, i just couldn't find the answer. I just cant seem to connect to the database.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04, if it helps.

Here is my code for `config.php`:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','121212aa');
define('DB_NAME','PHP-Wizard');
?>
```

And also `Database.php`

```
<?php
class Database{
public $host = DB_HOST;
public $username = DB_USER;
public $password = DB_PASS;
public $db_name = DB_NAME;

public $link;
public $error;

/*
 * Class Constructor
 */
public function __construct(){
    //Call Connect Function
    $this->connect();
}

/*
 * Connector
 */
 private function connect(){
    $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

    if(!$this->link){
        $this->error = "Connection Failed: ".$this->link->connect_error;
        return false;
    }
 }

 /*
  * Select
  */
  public function select($query){
    $result = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        return $result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }

  /*
   * Insert
   */
   public function insert($query){
        $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);

        //Validate Insert
        if($insert_row){
            header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Added'));
            exit();
        } else {
            die('Error : ('. $this->link->errno .') '. $this->link->error);
        }
   }

   /*
   * Update
   */
   public function update($query){
        $update_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);

        //Validate Insert
        if($update_row){
            header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Updated'));
            exit();
        } else {
            die('Error : ('. $this->link->errno .') '. $this->link->error);
        }
   }

    /*
   * Delete
   */
   public function delete($query){
        $delete_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);

        //Validate Insert
        if($delete_row){
            header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Deleted'));
            exit();
        } else {
            die('Error : ('. $this->link->errno .') '. $this->link->error);
        }
   }
```

And here is the error i get when i try to open `index.php`

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Forum/Database.php on line 23

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Forum/Database.php on line 35

Warning: Database::select(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Forum/Database.php on line 35
```

Any answers as to why i cant connect to the Database?

Comment: Are you sure the password is correct?

Comment: No, sadly. Can i check what my password is?

Comment: usually if a password was never assigned, don't enter one. `define('DB_PASS','');` try that.

Comment: If you don't know what your password is you can easily change it. If you are on localhost you can change it from phpmyadmin and if you are on cpanel you can change it from database options. Also i don't see in your code including config.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reasons are your database credentials are wrong. If you don't remember your password you can easily change. As you mentioned in one of comments (could reinstalling xampp fix it). Well it won't Instead try changing password

Visit

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
//Then visit
User > Select user and click edit privileges > Login Information
```

Here you can overwrite old password with new one

If you are on remote server (Cpanel) you can reset your password from database options

Also i don't see anywhere in your code including `config.php` make sure its including in you class file

Comment: I tried to edit privileges on phpmyadmin, but use root@localhost already had no password, so i deleted the password variables, nothing. I left the password field empty, still nothing. Next i tried including the config file, it says that the variables are already defined, and still gives the same errors.

Comment: Should i try connecting to a different database? Mby i did something wrong with this one?

Comment: Your wish . Try it if you get successful connection then its sure that its problem with login credentials not with your code

Comment: Also make sure user is assigned to `localhost` not to anyhost sometime that also causes problems

Comment: Just created a new database, testt, nothing in it, nothing changed, just linked it, it connected, and yes root user really had no password. I'll just make another DB since this one is empty, so i'll save us the trouble.  Thank you for your trouble

Answer (score 2):

check your mysql credential....

> You can reset the root password by running the server with
>   --skip-grant-tables and logging in without a password by running the following as root (or with sudo):

```
# service mysql stop
# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
$ mysql -u root

mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("YOUR-NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit

# service mysql stop
# service mysql start
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to check if your credentials are correct by going to the console and typing:

```
mysql -uroot -p121212aa
```

If you are getting the same error it is likely to be credentials.

Comment: This is what i get : ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: Perhaps this will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: Is MySQL configured to accept connections via a socket or tcp connection only? If you start the server and navigate to /var/run/mysqld/ can you see the socket file?

Comment: no socket file there, the /run/ folder is just empty

Comment: Could reinstalling xampp fix it?