# Error with php7 and mysql - mysql-server-5.6 not configured yet

Tags: php, mysql

- I've got a fresh installation of Ubuntu server 14.04.
- I have successfully installed php7.

But I'm getting an error when trying to install mysql-server / mysql-server-5.6.

I'm getting the following output:

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Searching whole evening for a solution (5 hours already) but can't figure it out. I've tried too many things to list here.

How I first installed php7:
- https://bjornjohansen.no/upgrade-to-php7

Solutions I tried:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/384234/e-mysql-server-5-5-installation-error
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/292865/upgrade-mysql-server-issue

Somehow managed to get this error (not anymore):
- [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Tried many more things that I can't even remember

Comment: So did you manage to clean up/purge your mysql installation? And or configure mysql-server-5.6? Another ting might be make sure to run `apt-get update`  Before doing any installation.

Comment: Yes, had it removed. Also deleted the folder /etc/mysql. Tried to reconfigure. Done an apt-get update before. Nothing worked. Getting the same error.

Comment: Did you check error logs? One other option to try to install mariadb(fork and drop in replacement of MySQL) `apt-get install mariadb-server` Unless you need some specific functionality from mysql. Use PHP mysql driver to work with it. https://mariadb.org/. Did check PHP 7 repository nothing funky there.

Comment: This question is more suited for http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

You can solve running this command

sudo apt-get install php-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try this (php5):

```
sudo apt-get install php 5-mysql
sudo apt-get update
```

Or this (php 7):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql
```

Then you will probably need to restart your webserver. E.g:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```