# Error to connection at the database: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: php, mysql

I have realized the database on a hosting website and not on the mac using MySQL. 
I use the database to SignUp/Login in an IOS app. The database is using a  PHP code for connecting.

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
if($_POST) {
    $Nome   = $_POST['nome'];
    $Cognome   = $_POST['cognome'];
    $Email   = $_POST['email'];
    $DOB   = $_POST['dob'];
    $password   = $_POST['password'];
    $c_password = $_POST['c_password'];

    if($_POST['email']) {
        if ( $password == $c_password ) {

            $db_name     = '****************';
            $db_user     = '****************';
            $db_password = '*********************';
            $server_url  = 'localhost';

            $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $db_user, $db_name, $db_password);


            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                error_log("Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"' . mysqli_connect_error() . '"}';
            } else {
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (nome, cognome, email, dob, password, c_password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $password = md5($password);
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $nome, $cognome, $email, $dob, $password, $c_password);


                $stmt->execute();

                if ($stmt->error) {error_log("Error: " . $stmt->error); }

                $success = $stmt->affected_rows;


                $stmt->close();


                $mysqli->close();
                error_log("Success: $success");

                if ($success > 0) {
                    error_log("User '$email' created.");
                    echo '{"success":1}';
                } else {
                    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Email Exist."}';
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Passwords does not match."}';
        }
    } else {
        echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Email."}';
    }
}else {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Data."}';
}
?>
```

This is the error that I see when I try my database:

> (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in **/srv/disk8/2129310/www/haer2jkqlgjql.co.nf/signUp.php** on line **20**

This error tells me that there are errors or there is an error in line 20, but I don't understand  the reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15039113/1817690

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Its syntax mistake**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $db_user, $db_name, $db_password);
```

**Right syntax is**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost',$db_user,$db_password, $db_name);
```

Comment: While this is correct, this won't solve the problem since he can't actually get a connection to the MySQL server.

Comment: Thanks @TomWright. But i answer the correction which i find at first view. now trying to solve more.

Comment: Thanks @devodedra but i don't work.