# Unable to start MySql service

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

When I run command

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I got an error

> **ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)**

When I try to run mysql service

```
service mysql start
```

it gets timed out with message

> **Job for mysql.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

Logs

> ```
> Jan 08 23:44:48 monal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 audit[30814]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=30814 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=123 ouid=0
> Jan 08 23:44:48 monal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 audit[30814]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/30814/status" pid=30814 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=123 ouid=123
> Jan 08 23:44:48 monal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 audit[30814]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/usr/my.cnf" pid=30814 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=123 ouid=0
> Jan 08 23:44:48 monal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1483899288.523:210): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/30814/status" pid=30814 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=123 ouid=123
> Jan 08 23:44:48 monal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1483899288.523:211): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=30814 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=123 ouid=0
> Jan 08 23:44:48 monal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1483899288.523:212): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/30814/status" pid=30814 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=123 ouid=123
> Jan 08 23:44:48 monal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1483899288.523:213): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/usr/my.cnf" pid=30814 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=123 ouid=0
> Jan 08 23:44:48 monal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 mysqld_safe[30539]: 170108 23:44:48 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
> Jan 08 23:45:01 monal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 CRON[30867]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
> Jan 08 23:45:01 monal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 CRON[30868]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
> Jan 08 23:45:01 monal-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 CRON[30867]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
> ```

Comment: Check with `ps ax  | grep mysql` if your mysql is running (I think not)

Comment: @Blag No, it is not running.

Comment: Same issue, did you ever solve this?

Comment: Same issue here and looking for a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: Could you please paste your *.ini file you are using.

Answer (score 2):

First stop the mysql instance. You will need to copy the exact /var/lib/mysql directory to your new data directory, preserving its permission. So use rsync with -a option

```
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /db/data/
```

Also change the data dir path in mysql.cnf file

You will need to add alias to apparmor so that it allows mysql to write to the new directory

To add alias:

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias
```

and then add this line to bottom

```
alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /db/data/mysql
```

Restart the apparmor

```
sudo systemctl restart apparmor
```

and now start mysql. It should work

Answer (score 0):

If your mysql is working and you want change your directory flow these steps:
change datadir from `vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
Change the owner or set high privilege for new directory 
`chown mysql.mysql /yourdir/mysql`
You should change `vim /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias`

`alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /yourdb/mysql`

finally add `/db/data/mysql r` and `/db/data/mysql** rwk` at the end of `vim /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`
`/etc/init.d/apparmor reload`
`/etc/init.d/mysql start`

But if your mysql doesn't work anymore remove it and the flow those steps.
If you need your data copy them to new directory.
remove steps:
`apt-get autoremove mysql-server`

`apt-get remove --purge mysql-\*`

`apt-get install mysql-server`

Answer (score 0):

**I add this answer to others who didn't find satisfying answer.**

First, follow a simple [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04) to copy and set aliases and configs to the new desired data directory (`datadir`).

The tutorial shows how to:

1. Stopping the mysql service,
2. Backup & Copy existing database to the new location
3. Adding AppArmor rules.
4. Rebooting the service.

Then, I had this exact issue (AppArmor access denied) when moving my `datdir` to `/media/data/mysql/`, and the final step (restart mysql service) failed due to `AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" prof.....`.

First, as @reihaneh mentioned, add AppArmor reading and writing rules:
Add `/db/data/mysql r,` and `/db/data/mysql** rwk,` (don't remove the commas) at the end of vim `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

**Finally, the only thing left to do (not mentioned in tutorials) is to change the privileges for the new datadir to the MySQL-Server user and mysql group**.

I used nautilus to do so:

**Run nautilus as SU (sudo nautilus) -> right click on the NEW datadir -> Properties -> Permissions**

Then choose owner: `MySQL - MySQL Server`
And group: `mysql`

Answer (score -2):

Just run this command

```
sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/ --ldata=/var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Hi, for me it returns : `mysql_install_db: [ERROR] unknown variable 'ldata=/var/dmh/mysql/'
2017-10-02 13:00:02 [ERROR]   Unrecognized options`