# Wordpress cannot connect to database after changing file permissions

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I was working on my wordpress website and changed file permissions in Filezilla in order to upload a file. Shortly after that, the database seemed to have crashed.

I can no longer log into the mysql server via SSH. I get the following error when trying to restart the server:

```
Failed to restart mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found.
```

I already tried the following:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql
```

But no result.

If I try to log into phpmyadmin it give me the following error:

```
 #2002 - No such file or directory<br />The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

I have changed the file permissions back to the original (755) but it's still not working.

Comment: Have you check are their any files inside that folder?

Comment: Yes the following files are in /var/lib/mysql: 

auto.cnf  debian-5.7.flag  ib_buffer_pool  ibdata1  ib_logfile0  ib_logfile1  ibtmp1  mysql  performance_schema  phpmyadmin  sys  wholesale  wordpress

Comment: Try this command to restart mysql `service mysql restart`

Comment: Doing that gives the following: `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` systemctl status gives a status=1/FAILURE at process:  `  Process: 31380 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

Comment: try starting your mysql

Comment: Trying to start it gives the following error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: try the solution of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: That did not work. The server was working fine before, but it seems that changing the file permissions in FileZilla messed something up

Comment: What do you get when you do a ps aux | grep mysql?