# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, xampp

I'm new to Ubuntu. 
I have xampp installed on Ubuntu and works just fine. But when I am trying to run `mysql -u username -p pass` from terminal I recieve this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'.
```

I've tried to install `mysql-server` again but it runs completely separate (has another database....and is not working with phpmyadmin from xampp).

How can I make it work in terminal from xampp server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql-database might not be running at all!

Try this: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start then mysql -u yourusername -p yourpasswrd`