# Can't connect to local MySql server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, archlinux

I'm using Arch Linux. I've installed mysql by aurget. Then when I'm trying to make some data base I face the error: `"Can't connect to local MySql server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"` What should I do to resolve my problem?

Comment: Any reason you didn't install the `mariadb` package, which is the default implementation of MySQL in Arch Linux?

Answer (score 6):

In Archlinux, services are not enabled or started automatically after installation (unlike Debian/Ubuntu, for example). According to [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MariaDB#Installation), after installing the `mariadb` package you need to run (as root):

```bash
mariadb-install-db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
systemctl enable mariadb.service
systemctl start mariadb.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my problem. It will be lesson for me. I should just update packages with sudo pacman -Syu and mysql start working.