# While trying to reset root mysql password in ubuntu I get error while running 'sudo mysql -u root' command

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lamp

I have run into a very common problem while setting up a lamp stack in ubuntu. The problem that I got into is, I try to log into phpmyadmin using 'root' as username and a password that I set during instillation, I don't know if the password is wrong or I forget or something  else went wrong, any way I can't login. Now I search For the solution to reset the mysql password and I get the most suggested solution which is like below:

```
  sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
  sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
  sudo mysql -u root
```

And during this third step I get the error like below:

```
  ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

And Now I am stuck here, And I cannot reset password: So Help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Comment: Its not duplicate first try to understand my question.

Comment: Starting and stopping doesnot solve the problem as given in the question that you have marked as a already asked one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me stopping and starting mysql did not help ('sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop', 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start')
Because I had to use the command to stop mysql:
     sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
and then run other commands
     sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
     sudo mysql -u root
before starting mysql:
     sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

But simply restarting my system that is my laptop solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/my.cnf`, the socket file config may be `/tmp/mysql.sock` and in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` the socket file config may be `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

So, remove or rename `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, let MYSQL use `/etc/my.cnf`, then the problem may be solved.