# mysql_secure_installation ERROR 2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-error-2002

After installing Mariadb on Debian 9, I am trying to run /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation. The script starts okay, but after I press 'enter' for no root password, I get the following error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

I have to ctl-c to get out of the script.

The socket is set in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf to /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
It is also set in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf to /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

The server is not running.

Comment: visit this URL- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Comment: I agree that there are a lot of posts with this error, and I browsed many of them going down a rabbit hole of checking config files. I felt it would be useful to have a question with the answer about starting the server when all configs are correct.

Comment: First you need check status. Is mysql running or not? Then Check file permission  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Answer (score 0):

After digging around many, many places, the answer was right under my nose on the Troubleshooting Connection Issues page at the MariaDB website [1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/troubleshooting-connection-issues/)

The error means that the server is either not running or running on a different port, socket or pipe. Since I knew the server was not running, I started it with

> /etc/init.d/mysql start

before running the script and no more problems with the error or the script.