# how fix 'ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to install docker in a laravel project. Everything seems to work, except that when I try to import data into my comic, I get this error:

I import width command line:

`docker-compose exec app php artisan db:import --local`

I must also say that this is a large amount of data that I am trying to import

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

I did research on the internet to find a solution. I saw many but none walked with me.

I use docker to create a development environment. Here are my configurations

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1.20-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mysql-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

#### docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    #restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - db
      - webserver

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "13306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: merchline
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11657829/1764442

Comment: How do u try to import the data?

Comment: hi Ntwobike. this is a command line to import the data: ```docker-compose exec app php artisan db:import --local```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to DB that **running** in docker container.

So you probably **need to use tcp** (which runs on 13306 port in your case) instead of unix socket in your PHP code.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Indeed, I connect to the database via the docker and it is in this situation that I have my error. My command is ```docker-compose exec app php artisan db:import --local```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mysql client can't reach the virtual host for your mysql instance.

You should set that info in your Laravel's .env file.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=13306
DB_DATABASE=merchline
DB_USERNAME=*your_mysql_user*
DB_PASSWORD=********
```