# How to solve error mysqli_sql_exception #2002 in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am using codeigniter framework latest version, when i call the function `$model->findAll();` it gives me error like below and my operating system is Ubuntu 19.10, if this error is because of operating system than please let me know how to solve that

[image]

Here is my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

// ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
// error_reporting(E_ALL);

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use App\Models\Users as CodeIgniterUsers;

class Auth extends ResourceController
{
    public function login()
    {
        $model = new CodeIgniterUsers();
        return $model->findAll();
    }

    public function register()
    { }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: Can you show the Users Model !!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe `App\Models\User` is not in the `namespace` yet.

Comment: tghis does not help the original author solving his problems, can you explain in more detail what you mena by this statement ?

Comment: Check @Boominathan Elango's comment. Asking for the `UsersModel`, because maybe the `UsersModel` doesn't have `namespace`.