# MySQL server is running but I cannot connect : ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

The client doesn't in work running Ubuntu.

```
mysql -u root -p gives

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Messed up the mysql-community installation, first did

```
tar --strip-components=1 -XJf /usr/home/lasse/mysql-8.0.18-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.xz
```

at `/usr/local`

Couldn't start mysqld so I abandoned it and downloaded the Debian bundle.

Installed the client and  the server and several other dependent packages with 
sudo dpkg -i, and finally got mysqld up and running somehow but I cannot connect to it.
Reading 
[ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)
gives that I should have a `/etc/my.cnf`, so I copied it from `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
What should I try next?

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/my.cnf` you should have:

```
[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
[mysqld]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

(or other, but the same for both sections file)
or have in the file

```
[client]
port = 3306
[mysqld]
port = 3306
```

This will make client to connect to server via socket (first case) or via TCP port

Comment: Added both of your suggestions but it still doesn't work.

Comment: did you restart the server?

Comment: Must have really messed up. Restarted but got
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Do you have this path? `/var/lib/mysql/` Is it owned by mysql user?

Comment: I have it
root@Lenovo:/var/lib/mysql# ls -la

      total 168020

       drwxr-x---  6 mysql mysql     4096 dec 23 17:02 .

       drwxr-xr-x 68 root  root      4096 dec 23 15:03  ..

       -rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql       56 dec 23 15:03  auto.cnf

        shorting the list

         drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql     4096 dec 23 17:02 '#innodb_temp'

        drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql     4096 dec 23 15:03  mysql

        -rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 25165824 dec 23 17:02  mysql.ibd

Comment: Check if you have other directives in config and mysqld sections which can mess the things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204744/discussion-between-lasse-karagiannis-and-romeo-ninov).