# Can't see mysql databases

Tags: mysql

I had a mysql connection problem on ubuntu. I was not able to start mysql service.

It was giving  `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` error.

I tried to fix this error by these commands:

```
mkdir /var/run/mysqld/
chown mysqld /var/run/mysqld/
```

After this I can't see my databases in mysql.

What is the problem? What those commands affected to on databases? Or this is about configuration problem?

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Does `mysqld.sock` exist in the directory?

Comment: Have you tried all solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)?

Comment: I tried. But I didnt install mysql again with "sudo apt-get install mysql-server"   command since it will delete databases.

Comment: @NasirRiley No it doesnt exist. Is this creating by mysql server? Does it need to create manually?