# Repairing big mysql table with myisamchk without killing the server

Tags: mysql, database

Having a mysql table which is 50G and created with myisam index. 
I would like to repair it (it went corrupt) and I am attempting a myisamchk on it. 
THe problem is that it is taking too long and the Load Average on the server goes up (close to 30 or more). 
I am actually using:

```
 myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state \
> --key_buffer_size=512M --sort_buffer_size=512M \
> --read_buffer_size=4M --write_buffer_size=4M \
> tablename.MYI
```

any suggestions on the myisamchk arguments that will do a slow repair without overloading the processor?

Comment: Try adding --verbose to check status and progress of the repairing. Also, time depends largely on the amount and complexity of indexes (composite keys) not the table size itself. Check this parameter as well http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk-repair-options.html#option_myisamchk_quick .

Comment: thx setsuna. I will add verbose for some info

Comment: Solved following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297592/how-to-fix-error-130-hy000-incorrect-file-format